# How to add the Keycloak role offline_access to a newly created user via keycloak_admin_client?

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak

I am using the keycloak-admin-client 20.0.1 in Spring Boot 2.7.4 application and want to add the additional role ***offline_access*** automatically to the role mapping of certain users. Something like this...

```
private final static String USER_ACCESS_ROLE = "machine";
private final static String OFFLINE_ACCESS_ROLE = "offline_access";

var userAccessRole = realmResource.roles().get(USER_ACCESS_ROLE).toRepresentation();
var accessOfflineRole = realmResource.roles().get(OFFLINE_ACCESS_ROLE).toRepresentation();
userResource.roles().realmLevel().add(List.of(userAccessRole, accessOfflineRole));
```

I can add other self defined roles, but not the predefined ***offline_access*** role. I don't get any exception or error message.

My Keycloak admin client looks like this:

```
    private Keycloak getKeycloakInstance() {
        return KeycloakBuilder.builder()
                .serverUrl(env.getRequiredProperty(KEY_KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_URL))
                .realm(env.getRequiredProperty(KEY_KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_REALM))
                .username(env.getRequiredProperty(KEY_KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_USERNAME))
                .password(env.getRequiredProperty(KEY_KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD))
                .clientId(KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_CLIENTID)
                //.scope("")
                .grantType(OAuth2Constants.PASSWORD)
                .resteasyClient(ClientBuilder.newBuilder().build())
                .build();
    }
```

I did not set the scope here, but if it is set to "offline_access" it doesn't help.

**UPDATE**
I've updated Keycloak from version ***15.0.1*** to ***19.0.3*** and now it's working without any other changes!

Comment: `offline_access` is a scope to request refresh-token (not a user role), are you sure you are not confusing scopes and roles?

Comment: Actually you reqest an Offline token, but look at the Keycloak documentation [link](https://wjw465150.gitbooks.io/keycloak-documentation/content/server_admin/topics/sessions/offline.html), it says: ***To be able to issue an offline token, users need to have the role mapping for the realm-level role offline_access. Clients also need to have that role in their scope***.

Comment: You are are right about `offline_access` being a Keycloak realm **role** too, I had never noticed it was there. Does your "admin" client (the one that runs the code in your question) request the `offline_access` **scope**? Last you might have typos in your question: shouldn't you have written `offline_access` only (and not `access_offline`)?

Comment: Thanks @ch4mp, I fixed the typos and add the code for the Keycloak admin client.